# Меняю значение в Store но render() не вызывается

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Проект на ReactJS + Mobx; При создании экземпляра своего класса передаю в конструктор ссылку на observable массив из Store; Затем в асинхронной функции моего класса Записываю новое значение в observable переменную, но ничего не происходит - render() судя по всему не вызывается ... Что я забыл сделать ?!

```
class Store {
  arrData = [ 
    {name: 'TestUser1', sp: 'SP 1'},
    {name: 'TestUser2', sp: 'SP 2'}
 ];
}

decorate(Store, {
  arrData: observable
})

const appStore = new Store();

const MyPokedex = require('./pclass');
let myP = new MyPokedex(appStore.arrData);  // передаю в конструктор
//                    this._linked_appStore_arrData = appStore.arrData
myP.FillDataRows();   // - внутри меняется значение observable
// -----------------------------------------------------------
self._linked_appStore_arrData = self.dataRows.slice(0,self.namesOnPage-1);
// В консоли я вижу что значение изменилось !
// -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Покажите код у класса " MyPokedex". В mobx с массивами свои приколюхи есть.

Comment: Покажите код render. Observable переменные должны там быть вызваны явно, без декомпозиции, без "переприсвоения" в локальную переменную